# Liferay hook path access without login

Tags: java, liferay, hook, public

I have to work with Liferay in work atm, and absolutely new to that (shit).
I successfully created a custom hook I can call via http://localhost:8080/c/portal/myhookname 
and it shows me what I wanted to reach with my Action.

The problem now is, when I call this path, I have to login first to get the content.
But later a machine will call this path, and it doesn't matter if the person calling this path is a guest or something else.
So I tried to find something, to give access for everybody on this hook.

The BlablaAction.java is extending from BaseStrutsAction and returns the jsp in it's execute method.
Please somebody can help me.

Comment: Cross post :https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/58110812

Answer (score 0):

You can use portal property auth.public.paths to allow public access to custom struts path.

```
auth.public.paths=/portal/myhookname
```

You can override/extend this portal property in plugin-hook itself. Refer to [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/extend-override-portal-properties-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try this immediately.